# Chrome Opening Tab With Window.Open

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Have looked at the answers to previous questions and am not sure if it 
is the same issue as I am having. Some of the possible answers I have found
on the net are aged so am not sure whether anything has changed regards this.

I have this code to check for a cookie and then either open one or two 
tabs dependent on whether a cookie is found.

On the html side I have a link like this:

```
<a target='_blank' onclick="newTab()" href="http://www.test.com">
```

In the head section the newTab() function does the cookie check then
if needed opens a window like this:

```
window.open('http://www.test.com/members/','_blank');
```

When the link is clicked the above works fine in Firefox and IE and both
windows open when needed but in Chrome only the onclick tab opens and not 
the main url regardless of the cookie.

I imagine this is an issue relating to opening tabs/windows in Chrome but
I thought that the above would be dealt with by Chrome as the opening windows
are the result of a user click.

Am I missing something simple or is it a restriction on Chrome?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Possibly the popup blocker at work somehow? Since this is most often used to open advertising popups when the user clicks on a link. Or maybe because you used `_blank` as the window name, and use that same target on your link?

Comment: Yep looks like it is because of the _blank used twice - will have to change one I think...

Answer (score 0):

Indeed as answered by CBroe the reason for the problems was because
I had used _blank as the window name for both.

I changed one over to _parent and it is at least working like this now
so thanks for the assistance.